# Deleting folders is a risky business

Tags: c#, .net

Deleting folders programmatically is extremely dangerous. It is enough for somebody else to change a configuration file or constant variable including the target folder's name to, say C:\, and that's it: the workstation is paralyzed!

The following suggested methods are to prevent such a situation. Their aim is to wrap the low level, possibly recursive file system operation with the necessary validation and clear facade - look twice, delete once.

**Delete temporary directory created by current user (non recursive!)**

```
/// <summary>
/// carefully remove directory and its files
/// verify the directory is located under the %temp%
/// and it is not e.g. C:\
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dir"></param>        
public static void DeleteTempDirShallow(string dir)
{
    // check if it is an invalid directory path,
    // e.g. a disk drive or just a bad string
    if (! Directory.Exists(dir)) return;

    DirectoryInfo userTempDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetTempPath());
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

    if (dirInfo.FullName.Contains(userTempDirInfo.FullName))
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            file.Delete();

        dirInfo.Delete(); // just clean up the empty dir
    }
}
```

**Delete temporary directory created by current user (recursive!)**

```
public static void DeleteTempDirRecursive(string dir)
{
    // check if it is an invalid directory path,
    // e.g. a disk drive or just a bad string
    if (! Directory.Exists(dir)) return;

    DirectoryInfo userTempDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetTempPath());
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

    if (dirInfo.FullName.Contains(userTempDirInfo.FullName))
    {
        dirInfo.Delete(recursive: true);
    }
}
```

**Do I try to delete any root or system folder?**

```
static List<string> systemDirs = new List<string>
{
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.PrinterShortcuts),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),
};

/// <summary>
/// check if the argument dir is adisk drive,
/// is a system (sub-)folder
/// and should not be erased
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dir"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool IsSystemOrRootDir(string dir)
{
    // check if it is an invalid directory path,
    // or just a bad string
    if (! Directory.Exists(dir)) return true;

    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

    // is it a root (disk drive)? 
    if (dirInfo.Parent == null) return true;

    bool result = false;
    systemDirs.ForEach(sysDir => { result = result ||
                                   dirInfo.FullName.Contains(sysDir); } );
    return result;
}
```

**References**

[How to check if directory 1 is a subdirectory of dir2 and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3525950/1171019)
[How to delete all files and folders in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1288718)

Comment: This of course won't prevent the program from deleting the folder that _it's_ running from... or the directory of the CLR either.  It's also (at the moment) going to only 'work' on one OS, and potentially only specific versions too (are either of the `System` folders "System32"?).  That entire list should also be loaded from a resource file, so that it would be customizable.  Please note that generally speaking, programs should be running in as restricted a mode as possible, which could mean **OS-level** protection (using UAC).

Comment: hi @X-Zero, the `System` points to the `%windir%` environment variable. The `SystemX86` points to either `%windir%\System` in win32 or to `%windir%\System32` in win64. This code is supposed to work on all versions of MS Windows, supporting .NET.

Comment: The CLR directory was located under the `%windir%\assembly` up to .NET 3.5. The .NET 4.0 has moved the location of the GAC to `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC*` directories. Both the folders are located under the `Environment.SpecialFolder.System` and the `IsSystemOrRootDir(string dir)` would return true. So this case is covered completely with the code suggested.

Comment: Okay, I'll admit that I missed the 'Contains()', but if you're advocating this as library code, you're only going to frustrate people - expecially if `UserProfile` contains the `Users` directory.  What happens if somebody is attempting to use it for resource management (for content creation, say)?  You've just disabled the ability to reorganize their work...  And when I was speaking of different OSes, I was referencing Mac/Linux, not necessarily just Windows (yes, I know running on those platforms isn't common, but if you're claiming safety, it needs to be safe everywhere).

Comment: X-Zero, I agree about the `UserProfile`. I guess it worth splitting the IsSystemOrRootDir method by adding another IsPersonalRootDir function.    Now, about the different OSes, would you like to post some code, portable to them? Is it relevant at all the C# on Mac/Linux?

Comment: I don't happen to know right off what the Mac/Linux equivalents are (linux especially), or that they're necessarily all that relevant.  Your basic problem is that the list isn't configurable - it's effectively hardcoded.  Were I to use something like this, I'd like to be able to pass in my own list - there's no way for a **library** to know all of **my** important folders.  It'd probably be better for you to also set it up as a `whitelist` - it's too easy to delete 'something else' important... which by default is what UAC (on win 7) does.

Comment: I don't see the point of this code.  If you don't want a directory deleted then don't point it at something that deletes folders.  ACLs and ordinary permissions should prevent you from doing the worst damage.  And if the caller managed to do that kind of damage they presumably can deal with the consequences (or if not, deserve what they get. :-))  Even if you manage to ignore all that... this code is complex and brittle, pulls randomly from environment variables. I would not call it elegant.  You also commit the classic misguided file system race condition of `if (exists) { do something }`

Comment: @asveikau thanks for your comment. Would you like to get into details about the following:
"classic race condition" -what is the exact scenario?
"this code is complex" - how would you make it more elegant?
"they presumably can deal with the consequences (or if not, deserve what they get." - there are possibly multiple developers in the project. I'd like to protect my code from quick and dirty  changes in the erasure area.
thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelG - The classic race condition is thus: Checking for the existence of a file at time `t` says nothing about the existence of a file with that path (or even if it's the same file) at time `t + 1`.  The file can be renamed, another one with the same name put in its place, etc.  Checking the existence of a file is also not always a quick operation, so in addition to gaining nothing it takes time.  The "right" way is to just open the file and handle the "not found" case if you need to do something different there.  As for how to make the code less complex: remove it.

Comment: So the race condition is like this: 1. `if (! Directory.Exists(dir)) return true;` 2. `dirInfo.Delete();` 3. what is the worst case? The checked dir has disappeared; but hey, it is not a problem. We anyway wanted it to be deleted!

Comment: @MichaelG - Execuse me, but what the heck is the point of this post?! I see no questions in your post (other than a code example subsection marked as a question, which is not relevant to the post itself). Please ask something specific! Eg: Have I accounted for all possibilites? Have I missed some important folders? (which have been pointed out in previous comments by the way) Is there a better way to go about protecting from wrongful deletion? (again already pointed out, UAC, ACL and others. I would also say only allow deletion in c:\Users\<User>\.... anything else is bad!) etc...

Comment: @Marko, this is Code Review - the question is *always* "How can I improve my code", and doesn't need to be stated.

Answer (score 8):

### When all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.

> You're trying to do something with code, that's not the code's job. **Delete all this code** and tackle the problem at the root: **make sure your code runs with the appropriate permissions**.
>
> It's that simple.
>
> -- My humble opinion

---

> **Deleting folders is a risky business**

Indeed! If your running code doesn't have permission to wipe out your hard drive, you have some exceptions to deal with, i.e. you should wrap I/O calls in a `try...catch` block.

Comment: [I knew that phrase sounded familiar!](http://synoptek.com/Dev-Blog/beware-the-golden-hammer-of-software-development/)